# Browser client requires login for every new session

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am porting my idsrv3 based MVC application to aspnet-core and idsrv4.

Differently than in idsrv3 a new login is required whenever a new browser session is started. I also verified this changed behavior in the original github-samples idsrv3-aspnet5 and idsrv4-MVC and API.

In the log files I have seen that idsrv4 handles the authorize request of a new session always as not authenticated and directs me to the login. In idsrv3 the request handler immediately sends back the authorization form, when the user is already known.

Why does idsrv4 behave different?